# How to recompile a user defined function in SQL Server when a dependency is updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table valued function A that calls table valued functions B and C. Functions B and C are being updated (altered) as part of a migration however table A is not being updated as a result of this. How can I rebuild A without altering it?

Example (rollback is just added for convenience) [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14627/3):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE DOGS
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO DOGS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Rocky', 12);
INSERT INTO DOGS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Sammy', 2);
INSERT INTO DOGS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Porthos', 5);

CREATE TABLE CATS
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO CATS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Mr. T', 15);
INSERT INTO CATS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Old Timer', 37);
INSERT INTO CATS VALUES (NEWID(), 'Mittens', 1);

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

GO
CREATE FUNCTION [GetCatsYoungerThan]
(
   @age INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT Name FROM CATS WHERE Age < @age
);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [GetDogsYoungerThan]
(
   @age INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT Name FROM DOGS WHERE Age < @age
);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [GetAnimalsYoungerThan]
(
   @age INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT * FROM [GetCatsYoungerThan](@age)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [GetDogsYoungerThan](@age)
);
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDogsYoungerThan]
(
   @age INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT Name, Age FROM DOGS WHERE Age < @age
);
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCatsYoungerThan]
(
   @age INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT Name, Age FROM CATS WHERE Age < @age
);
GO

EXEC sp_recompile '[GetAnimalsYoungerThan]';

--results
SELECT * FROM [GetAnimalsYoungerThan](15);

--Shows expected results
SELECT * FROM [GetCatsYoungerThan](15)
UNION
SELECT * FROM [GetDogsYoungerThan](15)

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Result:

```
Name
-------
Mittens
Porthos
Rocky
Sammy
```

Expected Result:

```
Name    Age
-----------
Mittens 1
Porthos 5
Rocky   12
Sammy   2
```

My expectation is that `sp_recompile` would cause the function to be recompiled; however, that is either not happening or that is not good enough to update the values return by A.

My original plan was to recompile all the objects in the database using the following code but that requires `sp_recompile` to work.

```
DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT [ROUTINE_SCHEMA] + '.' + [ROUTINE_NAME] AS [NAME]
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE [ROUTINE_SCHEMA] = 'my_domain';

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ObjectName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Recompiling ' + @ObjectName + '...';
    EXEC sp_recompile @ObjectName;
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ObjectName;
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: This illustrates why 1) `SELECT *` is the devil and 2) you really want `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. Sure, now you get annoying errors, but at least things don't fail silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of using `SELECT *` and the result of that performing early schema binding of your TVF.

You can get the desired result by running:

```
sp_refreshsqlmodule <tvf-name>
```

Which effectively re-binds the schema to the TVF, without the verbosity of an `ALTER x...`

But in the long run, try and avoid using `SELECT *`.

Comment: Wow! My hats off to you. Worked perfectly.

Comment: In the future we will avoid `Select *` unfortunately this is an inherited database.